# Why is my function inside componentDidMount not being fired?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

In the following snippet, why is `this.setInterval` not being fired when the component mounts?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setInterval = this.setInterval.bind(this);
  }

  setInterval = () => {
    console.log('Set Interval');
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Test');
    }, 2000);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = this.setInterval;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the function all the while passing the reference.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = this.setInterval;
  }
```

should be

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = this.setInterval();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 setInterval = () => {
    console.log('Set Interval');
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Test');
    }, 2000);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = this.setInterval();
  }
```

You need to invoke setInterval() like so. In componentDidMount it gets executed only once during the initial load of the component.